# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS single.php on line 16

Tags: php, syntax-error

if anyone could help me with my code that would be great. I keep getting this error, on line 16. Everytime i open a post on my website i get the error. Pages seem to be working fine.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <h3 class="subtitle"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sb_subtitle', 'true'); ?></h3>
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <p class="postmetadataw">Posted by: <?php the_author_posts_link() |  on <span class="post_date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p> 

            <div class="content-ver-sep"> </div>
            <div class="entrytext"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumb'); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
```

I have been trying to fix my structured data with these errors:

```
hatom-feed
hatom-entry:    
Error: At least one field must be set for HatomEntry.
Error: Missing required field "entry-title".
Error: Missing required field "updated".
Error: Missing required hCard "author".
Error: At least one field must be set for HatomEntry.
Error: Missing required field "entry-title".
Error: Missing required field "updated".
Error: Missing required hCard "author".
```

Comment: Nobody cares to guess what line 16 is.

Comment: I'm guessing line 16 contains `<?php the_author_posts_link()`, which is missing the php closing tag `?>`.

Comment: what is this ?? not closing ---> <?php the_author_posts_link()

Comment: Or more likely, it's some kind of include... somewhere... and we don't get to see the content of that included file. No way that what he posted is (the entire) single.php, since it doesn't even contain 16 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It not the entire single php. I just posted the section i was just playing around with before the error happened

Comment: Syntax errors aren't instant-close any more?

Comment: i changed <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

Comment: and this piece: <?php the_author_posts_link()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close PHP section with `the_author_posts_link`. Try with:

```
<p class="postmetadataw">Posted by: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> |  on <span class="post_date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks this <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> did work :)